# Access Android files without entering pass-code

Tags: android, forensics, phone

I have a Samsung A5 from a friend. Her screen is totally broken (black) and she wants me to recover her files.
The problem is that you need to enter the pass-code of the phone in order to be able to transfer files to your laptop, but we can't enter the code because the screen is broken.

Now I am wondering if there is a way, to access the files from that Android phone from my laptop. We of course know the pass-code, but can't enter it on the phone itself. Ideally would be a way to get a password-input box on my laptop for the phone.
Maybe by using a specific Kali Linux Forensic tool?

We already tried those 'Samsung Data Recovery' crapwares but those of course didn't work at all.

**TL;DR**
How to access files on a phone connected to your laptop, knowing the phone's code, but without entering the code on the phone.

Edit: The closest option I got was using ADB (Android Debug Bridge), and sending the pass-code from command line using ADB, but USB debugging is turned of. I actually only need a way to force USB debugging on from my laptop.

Comment: Is the screen entirely broken, or just the display? If the touchscreen still works, you may have success printing a template from the internet to get the positioning right, and entering the code through it. I had to do that once. It was difficult and unpleasant, but not impossible. I really doubt there's any way to turn USB debugging on externally, or it'd be a massive attack vector for malicious chargers.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the A5 has microUSB 2.0, which means you _should_ be able to get a keyboard for it -- could you enter the passcode on that? It'd still be difficult or impossible to do anything to a phone with a nonfunctional screen, but it'd at least get it unlocked, and from there it's probably easier...